# Changing a <Type> Listbox backcolor

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a Listbox that holds a list of type customer. So my Listbox.Items is not of type ListItem anymore, it is of type customer.

I have an isActive flag in the customer field and I was wondering how I would set the back color say to red, if the isActive is true.

Currently I have tried this but it doesnt work since I can't cast Customers to type ListBoxtem

```
            List<object> inactiveCustomers = new List<object>();
        foreach (Customer item in ListBoxCustomers.Items)
        {
            if (!item.IsActive)
            {
                inactiveCustomers.Add(item);
                int index = ListBoxCustomers.Items.IndexOf(item);
                ListBoxItem x = (ListBoxItem)ListBoxCustomers.Items[index];
                x.Background = Brushes.Red;
            }
        }
```

EDIT:
I am calling a method that does the above code whenever I deselect a checkbox that is for active customers. Whenever I deselect the Active Checkbox, I iterate through the customers and display all of them, and at this time, I would like to change the backcolor of the inactive to distinguish which ones are inactve/active

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. The "correct" WPF way is to do it all in XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxCustomers" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

The WinForms-style way to do this in code-behind requires getting the container from the listbox. However, due to UI virtualization, not all items necessary have a container. Therefore, this code will only change the containers for the the current visible items. If the ListBox is scrolled, the new items may or may not have the setting you expect (depending on recycling rules).

```
List<object> inactiveCustomers = new List<object>();
foreach (Customer item in ListBoxCustomers.Items)
{
    if (!item.IsActive)
    {
        inactiveCustomers.Add(item);
        var container =  ListBoxCustomers.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListBoxItem;
        if (container != null)
            container.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the wpf example, it worked perfectly! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `ListBoxItem` you can use the `ListBox`'s `ItemContainerGenerator`. Make sure you do this after loading has completed, like in a `Loaded` event handler, since the controls don't exist yet before loading.

```
void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<object> inactiveCustomers = new List<object>();
    foreach (Customer item in ListBoxCustomers.Items)
    {
        if (!item.IsActive)
        {
            inactiveCustomers.Add(item);
            ListBoxItem x = ListBoxCustomers.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListBoxItem;
            if (x != null)
                x.Background = Brushes.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It managed to parse through it so that is a plus, but, x is now null. So it never gets background set.

Comment: Make sure you're running this after the ListBox has been loaded with data assigned. I put Window.Loaded as an example but you may have set things up differently in loading your data.

Comment: In addition to pre-load time, many WPF ItemsControl subclasses (list ListBox) utilize UI virtualization, which prevents the UI from creating a bunch of in-memory UIElements for items that are off-screen. That's another case when ContainerFromItem/ContainerFromIndex would return null. This is a good reason to do this all in XAML. If you do this all in codebehind, you have to manually detect when the ItemContainerGenerator creates new items and apply the settings manually.

Comment: I should have mentioned this in the OP, when the form loads, it is fine since it displays all the active customers only. But I have a checkbox to display all customers, and then I select this I want to show every customer and the ones that are not active will have a different backcolor to them. So my ChangeColorOfInactiveCustomer() method is being called after the window is loaded.